# Not able to show error message in Bootstrap Modal with MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I’m using a PartialView to populate a Bootstrap Modal. I’m trying to make it so that if there is an error that the error message would be displayed inside of the Modal and the modal not go away if that is possible.

Below is the code where I have an ActionResult that populates a view model and then opens up the PartialView. Then I have POST that will insert into the database. When there is an error I’m adding it to the ModelState error. I then have a check in the PartialView for any errors and if so it displays an alert.

What is happening here is that the error is getting created and added to the ModelState but it shows the PartialView as a whole page and because of that the _Layout is not included and the HTML is not formatted with CSS. In addition, like I mentioned, it is in it’s own page and not inside of the Modal.

Inside Form in PartialView

```
if (ViewData.ModelState.Any(x => x.Value.Errors.Any()))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "alert alert-danger" })
}
```

Controller code

```
public ActionResult ClockAddIPAddress(int clockId, string clockName, string clockDescription)
{
    var vm = new ClockIPAddressViewModel();
    vm.ClockId = clockId;
    vm.ClockName = clockName.Trim();
    vm.ClockDescription = clockDescription.Trim();

    return PartialView("_ClockAddIPAddress", vm);
}


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ClockAddIPAddress(ClockIPAddressViewModel vm)
{
    try
    {
        DAL.ClockAddIpAddress(vm);
        return RedirectToAction("Clock_Detail", new { id = vm.ReaderId });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error("Error adding Clock IP Address. {0} | {1} | {2}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException);
        ModelState.AddModelError("Error", ex.Message);
        return PartialView("_ClockAddIPAddress", vm);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing a full postback? Or is it via ajax? If it's via ajax, please show the code for handling the returned partialview content. If it's a full postback, you'll need to return a View, as opposed to a PartialView - by default, partial views don't include Layout content.

Comment: It's a full postback right now. I tried with just a "return View(vm)" but that still goes to a full page and then it says it can't find the view ClockAddIPAddress.cshtml, which of course there isn't one. I guess eventually I need to look at using AJAX.

Comment: If you save your partial view as ClockAddIPAddress.cshtml, you'll get away from that error, and you'll just need to iron out the final layout of this view.